# King of Tokyo: Omnivore

Tags: king-of-tokyo

Omnivore states the following:

> Once each turn you can score [1][2][3] for 2[Star]. You can use these dice in other combinations.

Does this only trigger when you are finished rerolling or at any time during rolling the dice?

Answer (score 4):

You only score dice at the end of your turn.  So if you had

1122233 (using extra dice from other cards)

You would score 2 points for the 123 (but only once), plus 2 points for all the 2s, for a total of 4 points.

Comment: How do you know that it's "only once"?  That's not obvious to me from the wording on the card.  It's never come up in our games so, there's never been an appropriately heated debate....

Comment: Well for starters, the card says "once each turn"...?

Comment: bwarner is right - the dice only take affect after you've finished rolling and re-rolling them, after that they're "locked in" and that's when you calculate what you get in terms of points, health, attacks, energy etc.

Comment: However, you don't score dice "at the end of your turn." You score them at [step 2 of your turn](http://iellogames.com/downloads/KOT_rules.pdf).